# How could the Lutece's plan ever possibly succeed?

Tags: bioshock

During the source of game play in BioShock Infinite, there is a lot of interaction with "alternate realities". One of the things that happens is that people cross over from one of these realities to another. When that happens, the person merges with the alternate-universe version of themselves, if such a person exists.

By the end of the game, is it eventually revealed that

> Booker DeWitt is an alternate-universe version of Comstock, whom the Lutece's have pulled into Comstock's universe to stop his plans for world domination.

But, shouldn't this plan have failed almost immediately? Shouldn't those two people have merged into each other the instant the former crossed over? More to the point

> Shouldn't Robert have merged with Rosalind as soon as he entered her reality?

NOTE: I've beaten the game but I have not found all of the Voxophones, nor read any supplemental materials, so I'm hoping there is an in-universe explanation; otherwise, anything "official" from e.g. the developers would be welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there's an issue with your understanding of trans-dimensional travel.

> One of the things that happens is that people cross over from one of these realities to another. When that happens, the person merges with the alternate-universe version of themselves, if such a person exists.

This isn't true.  What happened to Comstock, was that by repeatedly exposing himself to tears, his body was degraded.  When you're exposed to a tear, and the other space/time/dimension has a version of you in it, then you and your double blend together a little.  Constantly exposing himself to multiple futures caused this minor effect to accumulate over time, aging and sterilizing Comstock.

However, when you open a tear and travel through it to the other space/time/dimension, the above effect only happens once, and is minor.  The major issues Comstock suffered only occur through repeated exposure.

This is why the Lutece's plan succeeded (and for that matter, how they were able to abduct Elizabeth in the first place).  In the flashback to Elizabeth's abduction, we see Comstock and Robert in Booker's universe, with Rosalind in Comstock's universe.  Then they both cross over with Elizabeth.  If crossing universes resulted in the merging you describe, then Comstock wouldn't have been able to come to Booker's universe, nor would Robert have been able to go to Rosalind's (also Comstock's).

Comment: that's possible, but I'm pretty sure I got that 'merging' idea from within the game. Isn't that the whole point of the ending, though, that the two people in question merged together so the one could change the other's past?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield No, the idea with the ending was that Elizabeth sent Booker back to the time and place where his path forked.  Down one path lay him becoming Booker, the other path had him becoming Comstock.  By killing him then, no more Comstock, but also no more Booker.  There was time travel in addition to dimension hopping.

Comment: but those two universes were always separate; otherwise, how did one of them produce a male Lutece and another a female Lutece, even before Booker made his choice? Sending Booker "B" back into Booker "A"'s past to die wouldn't change Booker "A"'s choice unless Booker "A" ceased to exist... ?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Ah you're right.  It's not a forking. Instead, universes must be paired being paired, one with a Comstock and Rosalind, another with Booker and Robert.  The two universes share a connection at a quantum level, which enables the communication between the Luteces.  I guess I don't understand the ending as well as I thought.  The baptism scene would have to be some sort of nexus across multiple universes.

Comment: Well, I just read something about the DLC (which I haven't purchased yet) that implies that there are still an infinite number of universes where Comstock is still in power, so maybe the problem is that the ending isn't as final as the game implies...

Comment: (I still expect I'll mark this as an answer, as clearly there are things about trans-dimensional travel that I didn't understand from the game)